# Migrate Data To New SSD Drive Without USB to SATA Cable

Tags: data-transfer, ssd, migration

I just bought a SSD For my MacBook Pro. It is running Lion. I have a time capsule with a full backup, as well as an image of the entire drive I created stored on a network drive. How do I copy everything from the current drive to the new SSD? I don't have any cables, i.e. a USB to SATA, is this possible?

Is there a way if I install the SSD and boot into a safe mode, and load Disk Utility, and then simply load the image backup from the network drive?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32841/how-can-i-use-an-existing-time-machine-backup-with-my-new-computer for some tips.

Comment: This is a reason to make a bootable clone with a tool like SuperDuper or Carbon Copy Cloner. If you had that you could simply install the SSD, boot off the backup drive, format the SSD and copy back over it. I wish Time Machine had a mode that allowed this.

Answer (score 1):

I used an external 2.5" USB case. As @Richard suggested above, I also use Carbon Copy Cloner.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just install the news operating system to the SSD and then restore from the time machine backup you have on your time capsule?

To install, when i upgraded my system to Lion, if you find the installer file called. Install OS X Lion and right click and view package contents, there will be a file inside called InstallESD. If you restore that image to say a USB pen using disk utility or terminal, you then can boot to that USB pen by holding 'alt' on boot.

Or why not install the system that come with the machine and upgrade to Lion again. I believe the download allows you to install 3 separate machines. (correct me if im wrong)

Comment: How should he install Lion on the SSD?

Comment: updated my answer above.